# Solving the differential equation $x' = \frac{cx}{|x|}$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, polar-coordinates

Solve the following differential equation in $\mathbb{C}$. $$x' = \frac{cx}{|x|}$$

---

Here's the original question I encountered: There are A, B, C and D sitting on 4 vertexes of a square. They are all moving at a constant speed of $v$ towards others- A towards B, B towards C, C towards D, and D towards A. Since this movement is entirely symmetric(let the origin be in the middle of the square), $$|OA| = |OB|$$
OAB makes an isosceles right triangle, and hence $\angle{OAB} = \frac{\pi}{4}$; thus

$$ x'_A =  \left(-\frac{\sqrt2}{2}+\frac{\sqrt2}{2}i \right)\frac{x_A}{|x_A|}$$
Or in other words, $x' = A\frac{x}{|v|}$ with $A = [a, b; c, d]$ ,$a=d$ and $b=-c$.

I have solved this problem by letting $x = r\psi$ with $|\psi|=1$, which gave me the solution-something in the form of $r=r_0 - ut$. But I would like to ask if there is a more general way of solving ODE like this- perhaps without doing $x = r \psi$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that $|c|=1$ as in your example? That simplifies things greatly

Comment: @NinadMunshi It is in this case, but I would also like to see how to solve it otherwise.

Comment: did you mean isosceles right triangle?

Comment: Part of the problem of asking for a general method is that we are spoiled for functions $\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$. Every $f(x)\in\Bbb{R}$ has an antiderivative however the same cannot be said for many other functions. For example for real valued functions we'd have that $$\int\frac{|x|}{x}dx = |x|$$ but when $x\in\Bbb{C}$, the function $\frac{|x|}{x}$ does not satisfy Cauchy-Riemann so it does not have an antiderivative.

Answer (score 1):

Just directly integrating:

---

Suppose for a real constant $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and an unknown function whose $Im(x(t))\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, we have:
$$x' = \frac{cx}{|x|},$$
where $|x(t)| = \bigg\{\begin{matrix}x(t)&&\text{ if }x(t)>0\\-x(t)&&\text{ if }x(t)<0\end{matrix}$. 
Then provided $\color{red}{x\neq 0}$, manipulating and integrating w.r.t. the curve parameter gives:
$$\int\frac{|x|}{x}x'dt = \int cdt,$$
which upon *integrating the **LHS** by parts* with $u:= |x|$ and $dv:= \frac{x'}{x}dt$ gives:

---

Recall: IBP $\color{blue}{\bigg[\large\int \normalsize u\text{ }dv = u\text{ }v-\large\int \normalsize v\text{ }du\bigg]}$

---

$$LHS = |x|\big(\int\frac{x'}{x}dt\big)- \int\bigg(\big(\int\frac{x'}{x}dt\big)\cdot |x'|\bigg)dt.$$
To continue, we must evaluate the inner integral:
Apply IBP again with $u:= \frac{1}{x}$ and $dv:= x'dt$
$$\int\frac{x'}{x}dt = \frac{1}{x}\cdot x-\int x\cdot\frac{-1}{x^2}dt = 1 + \int \frac{1}{x}dt = 1+ln|x|+C$$
So we now have:
$$LHS = |x|\cdot(ln|x|+C)-\int(ln|x|+C)\cdot|x'|dt,$$
where $C$ absorbed the $1$. This, by Linearity of Integrals, equals:
$$=|x|(ln|x|+C)-\int|x'|ln|x|dt-\int C|x'|dt$$
$$= |x|ln|x|-\int|x'|ln|x|dt.$$

---

Using IBP a third time with $u:= ln|x|$ and $dv:= |x'|dt$ we get:
$$=|x|ln|x| - \bigg[ln|x|\cdot(|x|+D) - \int(|x|+D)\cdot\frac{1}{|x|}x'dt\bigg]$$
$$= |x|ln|x|-\bigg[|x|ln|x|+Dln|x| - \int x'dt-D\int \frac{x'}{|x|}dt\bigg].$$
Then distributing the negative, canceling the $|x|ln|x|$, and choosing $D=0$, we have:
$$LHS = \int x'dt = x+E$$
So finally, connecting this with the **RHS** ($\int cdt$), we get the original ODE implies:
$$x+E = ct+F$$

### $$\implies x = ct+a\text{ }\text{ for }\text{ }c,a\in\mathbb{R}$$

(by absorbing $-E$ into $F$ and renaming $F$ as $a$).

---

In a long winded proof, we found "a" potential solution to the ODE
$$x' = \frac{cx}{|x|}$$
is the line:

### $$\color{blue}{x = ct+a}.$$

Now we just test it:
$$x' = c\text{ }\text{ and }\text{ }\frac{cx}{|x|} = \frac{c(ct+a)}{|ct+a|} = \bigg\{\begin{matrix}c&&\text{ if }ct+a > 0 \\ -c&&\text{ if }ct+a < 0\end{matrix}.$$
So we see the requirement for our solution to work is just:
$$ct+a > 0\text{ }\text{ OR }\text{ }\color{red}{t>-\frac{a}{c}}.$$

---

Note that potentially more solutions may be found by not setting $D=0$.

Comment: If we change the meaning of $|x(t)|$ to be $Re(x(t))^2+Im(x(t))^2$ and allow for complex coefficients, trying the complex line forces the coefficients to be real (but doesn't require the red inequality).